# Как кастомизировать текст ошибки?

Tags: python, исключения

Мне надо переделать ошибку "NameError", но я не очень понимаю - как...
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Это заготовка:

```py
try:
   # do something
   pass
except NameError:
    print('Я такого - НЕ ЗНАЮ!')
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что Вы подразумеваете под "переделать ошибку"

Comment: Уточняю: Что бы при возникновении ошибки писался не стандартный текст, а мой

Comment: Не очень понимаю что не так с Вашим примером. Если в ваш пример между try и except вставить код, который вызовет NameError, то результатом вывода программы будет строка 'Я такого - НЕ ЗНАЮ!'

Comment: Спасибо, я не знал, что надо вставлять код)

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте как-то так:

```
try:
    raise NameError
except NameError:
    raise NameError('Custom NameError Message!')
```

Test script:

```
import sys

print(sys.version)

try:
    raise NameError
except NameError:
    raise NameError('Custom NameError Message!')
```

Output Python 2.7.8:

```
2.7.8 (default, May 19 2015, 02:50:14)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise NameError('Custom NameError Message!')
NameError: Custom NameError Message!
```

Output Python 3.3.2:

```
3.3.2 (default, Mar 20 2014, 20:25:51)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise NameError
NameError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise NameError('Custom NameError Message!')
NameError: Custom NameError Message!
```

Comment: Спасибо... Это у вас 2 варианта решения?

Comment: @АлександрБубнов, только что попробовал на разных версиях Python (2.7, 3.3) - output в ответе

Comment: К сожалению у меня не получилось, скорее всего виной мои ужасно маленькие знания языка, но все равно спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```py
try:
    #cod
except:
    print('ERROR')`
```

Вопрос задан 6 лет назад, но думаю до сих пор актуально (а ещё я не умею оформлять сообщение )

Comment: Этот ответ по сути ничем не лучше своего предшественника